# очень серьезный диспут по данному предложению. расставьте запятые

Tags: пунктуация

Гомерчик на время превратился в предусмотрительную дальнопланирующую Ксению)

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, насколько серьёзный спор может быть по пунктуации, если такого слова "дальнопланирующий" в русском языке нет. Это окказионализм, слово понятно: от "планирует далеко"(можно было сказать далекопланирующая), а предусмотрительная-дальновидная.

С одной стороны, разные качества - видеть и планировать(неоднородные определения), а с другой стороны, они характеризуют Ксению как умную, интеллектуальную. Так что можно считать определения однородными. В таких случаях автор решает, ставить или не ставить запятую.

Если нужно подчеркнуть, как она умна, запятую следует поставить, потому что "далекопланирующий" вроде бы даже сильнее.

Comment: "На время" обособленное обстоятельство?

Comment: По-моему, не стоит. Это обычное обстоятельство, поясняющим может быть толко как авторское.

Answer (score 1):

Гомерчик на время превратился в **предусмотрительную дальнопланирующую** Ксению.

1) Можно считать определения **неоднородными**. С одной стороны, названные качества  **не противоречат друг другу** и могут быть сопутствующими, с другой – это всё-таки **разные** качества.

**Из словаря:** ПРЕДУСМОТРИТЕЛЬНЫЙ,  Способный предусмотреть, предвидеть возможные последствия; дальновидный.

**Возможные синонимы для "предусмотрительный**": Дальновидный, опасливый, осторожный, благоразумный.

Предусмотрительный человек **предвидит последствия своих поступков**, например: "Или наоборот ― он очень предусмотрительный человек, заранее просчитавший все выгоды подобного карьерного перемещения"?

Но такой человек **не всегда строит планы на далекое  будущее**, хотя это и не исключается.

2) **Тем не менее однородный характер определений также не стоит исключать**, в этом случае мы будем считать признаки сближенными, сопутствующими.

Comment: "На время" обособленное обстоятельство?

Comment: Вы хотите обособить "на время"? Это авторское решение, зависит о содержания текста и от желания автора особо подчеркнуть факт того, что превратился только на время.

Comment: Людмила, извините, если Вас расстроил мой ответ, но мне кажется, что наши мнения совершенно не совпадают в части оценки признаков прилагательных по  однородности/неоднородности (абсолютно разный поход).  Я вообще хотела сначала остановится на одном варианте (неоднородные), потом уж в конце дописала фразу о возможности двойного толкования: признаки хоть и разные, но часто сопутствуют дуг другу, поэтому не стоит настаивать на одном решении.

Comment: Что касается рейтинга, то меня он вообще не интересует, да и что он может дать участнику? Это интересный форум, мне нравится решать лингвистические задачки, поэтому я здесь работаю. Также   приятно общаться с людьми, которым это тоже интересно.  Лично для себя я не вижу другой мотивации, но, возможно, другим людям это важно: азарт как в игре, рейтинг, конкуренция.

Comment: Попробую ответить на Ваш комментарий, совершенно для меня неожиданный. 1) Я отвечаю, когда мне есть что добавить. 2)  Чем больше ответов, тем лучше и информативнее сайт: он становится как бы объёмным, глубже видится проблема.  Это же коллективный форум, тем он и ценен. 3) Этика для меня - это уважительное и доброжелательное отношение к участникам, я никогда не перехожу  на личности, никого не обсуждаю, стараюсь корректно и вежливо отвечать на комментарии, при этом редко комментирую чужие ответы.

Comment: 4) Я с  сожалением вижу, что на сайте стали меньше работать симпатичные мне люди,  но думаю, что ушли они по другим причинам. 5) Конечно, меня огорчает ваша негативная глагольная риторика (блистать, разжёвывать, перебивать, влезать), но надеюсь, что это не единственное мнение о моём присутствии на форуме.